# Disable onclick with CSS :: Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to disable `onclick` event with CSS. Possible?

Let's say I have

```
<div id="btnCopy" class="button" onclick="btnCopy(this);"><img src="copy.png"></div>
```

and by adding class *"disabled"*

```
document.getElementById("btnCopy").className += " disabled";
```

I would like to turn off onclick event for this element, so `onclick="btnCopy(this);"` would not be active.

And by removing *"disabled"* class

```
document.getElementById("btnCopy").className = 
  document.getElementById("btnCopy").className.replace(/(?:^|\s)disabled(?!\S)/, '');
```

it would go back to normal, so `onclick` event will be active.

Comment: CSS is forstyling elements, not for reacting (or not) to events (except :hover stuff).

Comment: You can use html `disabled` attribute

Comment: `:hover` isn't an event either anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add some Javascript to your `btnCopy` function to check if the parameter-element has the `disabled` class or not.

Using CSS to alter the behavior of JavaScript is not possible. CSS is for styling HTML elements, JavaScript is for handling the behavior of events and the site. **CSS and JavaScript are two very different things.** The only thing that is possible with CSS is to prevent a user from clicking on an input (button for example). With the CSS solution, you are not disabling the code in the onclick event. You are only disabling the user's ability to trigger the onclick event.

However, there are many ways to alter stuff on a page (using even more JavaScript or with some plugins for your browser), which could make it possible to click on the button despite your CSS pseudo-element. That is why using CSS for this **is not recommended.**

Comment: That is what I am doing now, but... would be nice to have something neat with CSS..

Comment: As MarcB said as a comment to your question: CSS is for styling elements, not for handling events. You can't get it any more with CSS than that, unless you use the hackish solution buy Guy Fawkes to add an unclickable pseudo-element covering the button (which I think none of us would recommend).

Comment: @Ωmega Why would you want to do it with CSS when it's meant to handle things like this with JavaScript? Is it not better to use CSS in the way it's meant to be used and JavaScript in the way it's meant to be used?

Comment: @ SimonAndreForsberg - I am doing it that way now, but I was hoping to do it some neat fast way with CSS, as checking for class in every onclick is kind of old-fashion :)

Comment: And by fast you mean to save 0.00000001 milliseconds on each click?

Comment: @ SimonAndreForsberg - I mean faster coding, not executing :)

Comment: This solution is flawed, but it is written in strongly worded terms as if it is absolutely correct. The cursor change and button change on click would make it look like the user can click on the element, but it doesn't work. That is undesirable. The developer should be aware of the pros and cons and limitations of each solution. Depending on the exact situation, the ideal solution might be just JavaScript, just CSS, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 54):

You can do this.

```
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
```

more [here](http://techniblogic.com/how-to-disable-anchor-tag-href-links-by-html-css-javascript/)

(Note that this is not accessible; it does not disable tabbing to the element and pressing "Enter"; the event will still fire in this case.)

Comment: The cursor is ignored when `pointer-events` are set to `none`

Comment: Seems a risky fix, as it disables not only click but all pointer events (like hover).

Answer (score 31):

In some browsers you can set `pointer-events: none`, but that disables all mouse events not just clicks. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events/

Comment: Fully supported as of 2018! Change answer? https://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Answer (score 6):

It's hackish, but I would suggest using pseudo-elements:

On a button with a disabled class, you could create a pseudo-element covering the button so it's not clickable.

But it'd make more sense to use javascript since you're already using that to add and remove classes...

**EDIT:** Not recommended at all, but here you go:

```
#btnCopy {position:relative;z-index:1;}

.disabled:before {
  content:" ";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: It just doesn't make much sense to add a pseudo-element where you could just use JavaScript to do it (it's kind of its purpose, to handle the *behavior*)

Comment: @Ωmega It isn't exactly supported, it's just a side effect from the things that CSS do support. I have updated my answer with a little more details about the JavaScript vs CSS solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is how Bootstrap do it.

```
.btn.disabled, .btn[disabled] {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 0.65;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

You can just keep `cursor: not-allowed;` and if you don't need reset of the styles then you remove them `opacity: 0.65; filter: alpha(opacity=65); box-shadow: none;`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using javascript to add and remove class then why not just use it to enable disable the click event?

Comment: Because once I set `onclick=""`, then I don't know what was there before... I want to enable/disable buttons in bulk...

Comment: @Ωmega Just have a flag in javascript and in the onclick events in javascript check if the variable is true/false.  Otherwise just use the css disabled property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add or remove the class "disabled" you may as well check for this class in your event handler, and than do nothing it element has class disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to disable the buttons `onclick` event by adding this line of javascript.

```
var btnCopy = document.getElementById("btnCopy");
btnCopy.className += " disabled";
btnCopy.onclick = null;
```

The best option is probably to use jQuery and check if btnCopy has the 'disabled' class.

```
if(!$('btnCopy').hasClass('disabled')){
   //Add code to copy text here
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: How would you reverse `element.onclick = null;` back to the original, when `disabled` is removed? I need to turn on/off disabled class in bulk, for more elements. I don't want to set `onclick` for each element in separate line...

Answer (score -2):

```
<div id="btnCopy" class="button" 
    onClick="if(this.className.indexOf('disabled') == -1){btnCopy(this);}">
    <img src="copy.png">
</div>
```

it would have to be done with Javascript. An `if(indexOf('disabled') == -1)` should do the trick.

Comment: Just want to add, its not pretty. It would be better to do it inside the event handler or have a function in the middle do the check.

Comment: Also, simply using an indexof on the classname will match the class "notdisabled", if that would exist on the element.

Answer (score -3):

One way of doing it purely via CSS is displaying an unclickable-invisible overlay on hover.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FNVmh/1/

Comment: Anything wrong with this approach? Its uses only CSS pseudo-events for the purpose.. No JS even..

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use `input` elements inside for more reasons, one of them is focus...

Comment: Ok. but the input is disabled, so it wont ever get focus. any other reasons? (out of curiosity, so that i may learn something new..:)